# Правописание слова "сахаро(о)бразующий"

Tags: орфография, словообразование, сложные-слова

Допустимо ли писать слово **сахаробразующий** с двумя "о"?
В [**словаре**](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-ortho-term-77364.htm) — с одной "о", в интернете встречается написание с двумя "о" (причем в [**одной статье**](http://hlebinfo.ru/tema-9-saharoobrazuyushhaya-sposobnost-muki.html) встречаются оба варианта).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему, в большинстве словарей  с одной О

Образующий что? сахар .Мне тоже это кажется верным.

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/76938/%D1
Слитно или раздельно? Орфографический словарь-справочник. — М.: Русский язык. Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Какалуцкая. 1998.

А допустимо или нет - это смотря где. В научной работе пишем нормативно, по словарям, а в бытовом варианте - как хотите, никто ведь " 2 " не поставит.

Answer (score 4):

Хлебопекарные свойства муки зависят от ее **сахарообразующей и газообразующей** способности. Это **термины**, и они, скорее всего,  имеют одну форму написания.

[Хлебопекарные свойства пшеничной муки | hleb-produkt.ru](http://hleb-produkt.ru/hlebobulochnye-izdeliya/403-hlebopekarnye-svoystva-pshenichnoy-muki.html)

Сложные прилагательные в данном случае образованы способом чистого сложения основы существительного и опорного прилагательного с использованием соединительной гласной (сравнить: стойкий к морозу - морозостойкий).

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что это термин. Странно, что такое написание не зафиксировано в словаре.

Answer (score 1):

Могут быть разные подходы. Я тоже считаю "сахарообразующий" термином. Но двойное "О" объясняется не тем, что это термин, а общим подходом к образованию подобных слов. Во-первых, слова требуют соединительной гласной, а во-вторых, удвоенная она никогда не упрощается (два уродца "паралимпиада" и "Беларусь" имеют более политическое, чем лингвистическое происхождение).

Словарь, на который Вы ссылаетесь - какой-то левый, я так и не нашел на него выходных данных.